# Getting G-WAN to work with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, debian, g-wan

I have followed the instructions on the G-WAN site FAQ and read through the manual, but I can not get G-WAN to "see" the Mono installation on my Debian 6 (x64) setup.

I have tried with the recommended Mono version (3.0.2) and the latest(3.0.4).

I am using the latest (today's) version of G-WAN.

Have I missed some configuration (e.g. environment variables...) or do I need to run Mono as a daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mono by default installs on **"/usr/local"**.

Compiling mono 3.0.6 using

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Worked for me. It will install libmono*.so on **"/usr/lib"**

Answer (score 1):

G-WAN searches `libmono*.so` under `/usr/lib` and then links dynamically with it to compile C# scripts.

If you have installed Mono elsewhere then you should either provide links or re-build and install Mono (from source code) in the proper directory (which is simpler to do).

You can verify where Mono is installed by running:

```
find -L /usr/lib -name 'libmono*.so'
/usr/lib/libmono-2.0.so
```